# I want to replace XGBRegressor with a simple model to make feature selection

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, decision-trees, xgboost

I will make some for loop on to select the best features by my Data frame is big 10M row and about 50 columns so if i replaced xgb with a single Decision tree would it be the same results for the best features and i can choose them on xgb or it may differ, i just want to save time as much as possible.

Comment: It will differ. Why removing features?

Comment: because i have added many like interaction variables and so on and i need to remove some to prevent overfitting